How to append inline element to its parent by parsing
I want to make markdown parser and some elements can't append. in parsing there is steps i have seen tokenizing => parsing => rendering.
My problem is how to to append child to parent in Abstract syntax tree?
when i tokenize everything how does parser know this is parent of that child and build AST.
i think if i make inline-parser.
input = ## this is header and this is **bold** text in header
output:
Tokens: [
  {
    "type": "header",
    "depth": 2,
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "value": "this is header and this is "
  },
  {
    "type": "bold",
    "content": "bold"
  }
]

expected output:
Tokens: [
  {
    "type": "header",
    "depth": 2,
    "children": [{"type": "text", "value": "this is header and this is "},{ "type": "bold", "content": "bold" },{"type": "text", "value": " text in header"}],
  }
  
]

My tokenizer
export function tokenize(input: string): any[] {
    const tokens = [];
    const lines = input.split('\n');

    for (const line of lines) {
        const header = line.match(/^(#{1,6})\s(.+)/);
        if (header) {
            tokens.push({ type: 'header', depth: header[1].length, children: [] });
        }
        
        const text = line.match(/[^\#\*\_]+[A-Za-z\s]+/);
        console.log(text);
        
        if (text) {
            tokens.push({ type: 'text', content: text.join() });
        }
        
        const bold = line.match(/(\*{2}|\_{2})([^\s]+)\1/);
        if (bold) {
            tokens.push({ type: 'bold', value: bold[2] });
        }

    }

    return tokens;
}

I have no idea how to achieve that the main problem how to append it. and thanks anything will be appreciated.
I have idea to make inline-tokenizing is there other ways?
if there is any thing wrong with my my path tell me

Could you please create a working demo as to what you are trying to achieve and what is going wrong so that it is easier for everyone to follow, debug and provide solutions for it.

@Vibhor my goal is to build markdown parser i mentioned above, and if i can to create demo of what i want it will be good for me and i can't achived.

I would suggest you organize the tokens into a tree structure that represents the document's hierarchy in that way, it will be easier to convert the AST into the desired output format and convert the input markdown text into a stream of tokens
// For the Token
    export function tokenize(input) {
    const tokens = [];
    const lines = input.split('\n');

    for (const line of lines) {
        const header = line.match(/^(#{1,6})\s(.+)/);
        if (header) {
            tokens.push({ type: 'header', depth: header[1].length, content: header[2] });
            continue;
        }

        let pos = 0;
        while (pos < line.length) {
            const bold = line.substring(pos).match(/^(\*\*|__)(.*?)\1/);
            if (bold) {
                tokens.push({ type: 'bold', content: bold[2] });
                pos += bold[0].length;
                continue;
            }

            const text = line.substring(pos).match(/^[^\*\_]+/);
            if (text) {
                tokens.push({ type: 'text', content: text[0] });
                pos += text[0].length;
            }
        }
    }

    return tokens;
}

// For parsing
    export function parse(tokens) {
    const root = { type: 'root', children: [] };
    let currentParent = root;

    tokens.forEach(token => {
        if (token.type === 'header') {
            const headerNode = { ...token, children: [] };
            currentParent.children.push(headerNode);
            currentParent = headerNode;
        } else {
            currentParent.children.push(token);
        }
    });

    return root;
}

